# c++ boost causing crashes

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I wrote some multithreaded application with c++11 features and boost, but I got annoying problem.

code:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
Client c(io_service, server->hostname.c_str(), server->port.c_str());
io_service.run(); //here is problem , it causes crashes
```

bt:

```
#0 0x414910 std::vector<boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_entry<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, std::allocator<boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_entry<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >::operator[](this=0x0, __n=0) (/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:771)
#1 0x4131d4 boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::dereference(this=0x7fffdb7fd250) (/usr/include/boost/asio/ip/basic_resolver_iterator.hpp:183)
#2 0x411f24 boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::operator*(this=0x7fffdb7fd250) (/usr/include/boost/asio/ip/basic_resolver_iterator.hpp:123)
#3 0x40f8c6 Client::handle_resolve(this=0x7fffdb7fd800, err=..., endpoint_iterator=...) (*******Client.h:48)
#4 0x41c21f boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Client, boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::operator() (this=0x7fffdb7fd450, p=0x7fffdb7fd800, a1=..., a2=...) (/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:280)
#5 0x41bd3b boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Client*>, boost::arg<1> (*)() (/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:392)
#6 0x41b74e boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Client, boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Client*>, boost::arg<1> (*)() (/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:102)
#7 0x41adaf boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Client, boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Client*>, boost::arg<1> (*)() (/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:127)
#8 0x419fe1 boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Client, boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Client*>, boost::arg<1> (*)() (/usr/include/boost/asio/handler_invoke_hook.hpp:64)
#9 0x4191d8 boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Client, boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Client*>, boost::arg<1> (*)() (/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_invoke_helpers.hpp:37)
#10 0x41776c    boost::asio::detail::resolve_op<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Client, boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Client*>, boost::arg<1> (*)() (/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/resolve_op.hpp:112)
#11 0x409df4    boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete(this=0x7fffc8000db0, owner=..., ec=..., bytes_transferred=0) (/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp:37)
#12 0x40c4f7    boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(this=0x7fffc8000910, lock=..., this_thread=..., ec=...) (/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:384)
#13 0x40bf27    boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(this=0x7fffc8000910, ec=...) (/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:153)
#14 0x40c8a7    boost::asio::io_service::run(this=0x7fffdb7fdbc0) (/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:59)
#15 0x41d9a3    some_function(server=0x67e0b0) (*********Server.cpp:17)
```

Client.h

```
 void handle_resolve(const boost::system::error_code& err,
                            tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
        {
            tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator; //48 line
            ip_ = endpoint.address().to_string();
            if (!err)
            {
                boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, endpoint_iterator,
                                           boost::bind(&Client::handle_connect, this,
                                                       boost::asio::placeholders::error));
            }
```

Just edited and added client part.

Comment: You have to remember that the `c_str` function of `std::string` returns a *temporary* pointer. If you save these pointers and later use them you have undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks, my bad, it's obvious

Comment: it didn't help the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace, the problem is in `Client::handle_resolve`, line 48 of `Client.h`.

My best guess is that you're dereferencing an iterator without checking whether it's valid first. Perhaps you could post that function, if the error isn't obvious when you look at it.

**UPDATE**: My guess was correct: you're dereferencing the iterator before checking whether the operation succeeded. If it didn't, then the iterator won't be dereferencable.

Move the first two lines inside the `if (!err)` block.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know io_service in detail, I have to guess a little bit. Which platform are you using? On boost 1.41 we had the problem that in QNX the automatic multithread capability was not detected correctly and therefore BOOST_ASIO_HAS_THREADS may not be set. This leads to a null_mutex being used instead of POSIX or Windows mutexes. Since std::vector itself is not thread safe, this could lead to the race condition with the segfault.

Comment: i'm using debian jessie and boost 1.54